# [[Edited]] JWT spring security: How to have roles be read by .hasRole() or .hasAuthority(), where they look at the user roles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http, spring-security, authorization

I am trying to add an authorization to the spring actuator service using roles in the HTTP config but it doesn't work and the response is "forbidden 403" which means the user is unauthorized.
So My question is where exactly the .hasRole() finds the signed in user roles when using JWT token

Here is the **config method** in the class which extends **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** class

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenVerifier(jwtConfig), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ACTUATOR")
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().disable();
    }
```

Here I put the roles in the JWT Token

```
public String generateJwtToken(UserDetailsImpl userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        Set<String> Userroles = new HashSet<>();

        Role r1 = new Role();
        r1.setDescription("ROLE_ACTUATOR");
        r1.setId(1L);
        
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        roles.add(r1);
        
        for(Role role:roles){
            Userroles.add(role.getDescription());
        }
        claims.put("Roles",Userroles.toArray());
        claims.put("userId", userDetails.getId());
        
    return Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claims)
        .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
        
        .setIssuedAt(new Date())
        .setExpiration(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusDays(getTokenExpirationAfterDays())))
        .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(getSecretKey().getBytes())).compact();
    }
```

So what is wrong or missing? Thanks in advance
Here is an update of the JWT custom filter:

```
public class JwtTokenVerifier extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private JwtConfig jwtConfig;

    public JwtTokenVerifier(JwtConfig jwtConfig) {
    super();
    this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    if (authorizationHeader == null || authorizationHeader.isEmpty() || !authorizationHeader.startsWith(jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix())) {
        String requestParam = request.getParameter("token");
        if (requestParam != null && !requestParam.isEmpty() && requestParam.startsWith(jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix())) {
        authorizationHeader = requestParam;
        } else {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
        }
    }
    try {
        if (jwtConfig.validateJwtToken(authorizationHeader)) {
        String username = jwtConfig.getUserNameFromJwtToken(authorizationHeader);

        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request), null);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, e.getMessage());
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please see the [JWT Login](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login) sample. Note that you do not (and should not) provide a custom JWT filter.

Comment: You mean this line ".addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenVerifier(jwtConfig), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)" so why? it is already in the code I can't remove it. I am trying to add role to the existing code

Comment: The problem you're having is likely related to the custom JWT filter as that is where the roles would be populated. You haven't included how it is defined. You can replace the entire use of that custom filter with built-in features of the framework, as in the example link I posted above.

Comment: I can add the custom filter implementation above, unfortunately I can't remove it, it is not my code

Comment: I see. Then I would definitely recommend that you check with them to understand how roles are populated. The relationship between Spring Security's `hasRole` method and user authorities is handled by the authentication filter, in this case `JwtTokenVerifier`. Note that it is sometimes indirectly handled by an `AuthenticationProvider` used by a filter, but that's doubtful in this case, though I have no idea for certain how this filter is implemented.

Comment: I add the customized filter and in the project it never uses the roles so roles are not handled before in the project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239677/discussion-between-steve-riesenberg-and-programmer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SteveRiesenberg, as said in the chat **"if roles are not handled by your custom JWT filter, then that is the issue. Roles (authorities) must be populated when the authentication is performed."**
so since the roles are not handled in the filter, they are not passed through the security chain.
The code of the filter is edited as follows:

```
UserDetailsImpl userDetails  = (UserDetailsImpl) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = userDetails.getAuthorities();
                
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request), authorities);
```

Where the authorities are passed to the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` and `UserDetailsImpl` is the implementation of `UserDetails` class provided by spring

Answer (score 0):

In the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` extention, I see `ACTUATOR`, but in the user details definition I see `ROLE_ACTUATOR`. Is this a mismatch?

Comment: According to many references, spring add the word "ROLE_" before any role and when I put .hasRole("ROLE_ACTUATOR") it gives an error that spring will add automatically so it is not a mismatch

Comment: Is there any useful info if you run with `--debug` command line arg?

Comment: something like what? I don't find a difference but when I debug the code, it sees the role and set it in the object correctly but still don't know why HTTP doesn't see this role